# Distinct eigenvalues of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-mechanics

While studing Quantum Physics I've came to the conclusion that it would be useful to find an equivalent (or at least a sufficient) condition for a matrix (over $\mathbb{C}$) to have distinct eigenvalues.

Clearly I'm not looking for conditions that are too close to the definition (such as that the minimal polynomial is separable).

Can anyone think of any such condition?

If so, can it be generlized to any linear operator? (not necessaraly over a finitely generated vector space)

Comment: Could you give us a little more context?  What kind of operators are you looking at?  Why are you checking for distinct eigenvalues?

Comment: In qunatum mechanics a set of commuting operator is said to be complete if given an eigenvalue of each of those operators determines (up to proportion) a single eigenvector corresponding to those eigenvalues (recall that since they comute, they have a common eigenbasis). Physically this means that after measuring all those quanties (i.e operators) we know at which state (eigenvector) the system is at. Since only hermitian operators can stand for physical quantities, there is no problem reducing the discussion to hermitian operators

Comment: Try the gershgorin circle theorem. I don't know if that extends to infinite dimensional spaces, though.

Comment: See the explanation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem).  Certainly, it gives an easy to check sufficient condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT. In the formula, I forgot the $\det$.

$A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues iff $discriminant(\det(A-xI_n),x)\not=0$.

cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant

We may replace $\mathbb{C}$ with any algebraically closed field $K$.